# Sharing AR models between Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a problem that I have been trying to solve for a while now. I have 4 different Rails applications using the same database, meaning they need to use the same models and have the same migrations. I initially solved the problem by creating a Rails engine packaged into a gem, which then carries all the models and migrations with it. Now I realize that there are pieces of functionality that only one application needs, but the others do not - like for example the admin application needs to have methods for providing sortable tables for all models - the other applications do not need this functionality at all.

So my idea was to find a way where I can provide the "base" models from the gem, while augmenting these base models in my specific applications to add additional functionality when needed. What I tried first was inheritance:

```
class User < Base::User
end
```

This does not work though, because now you have 2 User models in your load path (User and Base::User) and when querying associations, it always picks the "closest" class for the associated record class - meaning when you have an Model::Account which belongs_to :user, it will pick Model::User as the association class, not User. I tried reversing the AR type compute method  but this only resulted in more problems.

I can technically provide all of my models from the base engine (gem), but the issue here is that how do i extend these models in my application? .class_eval feels really really dirty, inheritance does not work, providing base functionality as mixins means the "base" models do not feel and look like models at all. My goal would be to cause as little friction as possible for the other developers, I want them to be able to define their models in the gem like they do normally and then also have an easy way to extend that functionality in other applications.

Has anyone solved this problem before or have any suggestions? Or how do you guys solve this problem in your larger applications? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered wrapping the Data layer of your application in a Rails API which will be consumed by the 4 client apps?

Comment: Yes and I definitely do not want to do that. Working with AR models directly (and connecting to the db directly) is much faster and easier than playing around with exposing everything as an API. I need to go way beyond basic CRUD functionality on a lot of the models, and the overhead of building this plus using it is not worth it in my opinion. SOA is not the hammer for all nails :)

Comment: Is this really something so rare that no-one is doing...?

Answer (score 0):

This is mentioned in the [Rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers). It describes class modification with the Decorator pattern.

Comment: I would like to avoid using .class_eval/.instance_eval if possible, these tend to cause gotchas to some developers. The other thing is that ideally I would like the models in respective applications to work and look like normal models, using decorators which potentially have class and instance eval blocks in it are quite far off from that in my opinion.